# html5 time element question

Tags: html

What is the format to add a millisecond to my time element? I know the basic format is `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD` but what is it for the millisecond can someone give me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to section [2.4.5.4 of the HTML5 draft specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#times), you can do it with a dot '.' following the seconds value.

Quoting the current draft (emphasis mine):

> Optionally (required if second is non-zero):
>
> 1. A ":" (U+003A) character
> 2. Two ASCII digits, representing the integer part of second, in the range 0 ≤ s ≤ 59
> 3. **Optionally (required if second is not an integer):**
>
>    1. **A 002E FULL STOP character (.)**
>    2. **One, two, or three ASCII digits, representing the fractional part of second**

For example:

```
2011-02-27T12:00:00.123
```

In this example, the 123 is milliseconds.

Comment: where does is say that in the specs? a link please if you can?

Comment: Here you go: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/common-microsyntaxes.html#times The bit to note is section 4, where it talks about seconds.

Comment: I have updated my answer because the link in my previous comment has since disappeared.